# How can I add a bone constraint to multiple selected bones at once?

Tags: armature, bones, bone.constraints

I want to add the same bone constraint to every bone in my armature. I could do this by manually constraining each bone, but that would be time consuming on a complex armature. Is there a way to add the same bone constraint to multiple bones at once?

Comment: Constrain one bone.  Set the parameters as desired.  Select all bones that you want the constraint on, make sure your constrained bone is the actively selected bone, and use "copy constraints to selected bones" operation.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's got it.